# Error sending POST request to SendGrid using React and Express

Tags: javascript, forms, post, request, sendgrid

I'm developing a website that includes a contact form, and I'm using the SendGrid module to send the form data via email to ****@gmail.com. However, when I click the send button, the POST request does not work, and I receive the following error: "xhr.js:210 POST http://localhost:3000/send-email 404 (Not Found)".

I have checked the console to see if the values for the contact data have been correctly inputted, and it appears to be working fine. Here is the client-side code for my contact form in card.tsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import cardcss from "./Card.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

interface CardProps {
  imageUrl: string;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

function Card(props: CardProps) {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const nameInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const emailInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const messageInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (messageInputRef.current) {
      messageInputRef.current.focus();
      messageInputRef.current.setSelectionRange(0, 0);

      // Delay setting the cursor position
      setTimeout(() => {
        messageInputRef.current?.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
      }, 0);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleFocus = (event: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.target.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  };

  const submitHandler = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (
      nameInputRef.current &&
      emailInputRef.current &&
      messageInputRef.current
    ) {
      const nameInput = nameInputRef.current.value;
      const emailInput = emailInputRef.current.value;
      const messageInput = messageInputRef.current.value;

      const contactData = {
        Name: nameInput,
        Email: emailInput,
        Message: messageInput,
      };
      console.log(contactData);

      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3000/send-email", contactData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Received email request");
          // Handle success response
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          // Handle error response
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={cardcss.cardcontainer}>
      <div className={cardcss.imagecontainer}>
        <img src={props.imageUrl} alt="" />
      </div>

      <div className={cardcss.cardtitle}>
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>
      </div>

      <div className={cardcss.cardbody}>
        <p>{props.body}</p>

        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <div>
            <label className={cardcss.namelabel} htmlFor="name">
              Name:
            </label>
            <input
              className={cardcss.nameinput}
              type="text"
              id="name"
              name="name"
              ref={nameInputRef}
            />
          </div>

          <div className={cardcss.emailcontainer}>
            <label className={cardcss.emaillabel} htmlFor="email">
              Email:
            </label>
            <input
              className={cardcss.emailinput}
              type="text"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              ref={emailInputRef}
            />
          </div>

          <div className={cardcss.messagecontainer}>
            <label className={cardcss.messagelabel} htmlFor="message">
              Message:
            </label>
            <input
              ref={messageInputRef}
              className={cardcss.messageinput}
              type="text"
              id="message"
              name="message"
              value={message}
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
              onFocus={handleFocus}
            />

            <button className={cardcss.sendbutton} type="submit">
              Send
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

And here is the server-side code in server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
const { resolve } = require("path-browserify");

// Set up SendGrid API key
sgMail.setApiKey(
  "********"
);

// Create Express app
const app = express();

// Middleware to parse JSON requests
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello, server!");
});
// Route to handle sending emails
app.post("/send-email", (req, res) => {
  const { Name, Email, Message, submitbutton } = req.body;

  const msg = {
    to: "paristiffany12@gmail.com",
    from: "paristiffany12@gmail.com",
    subject: "Example Subject",
    text: `Name: ${Name}\nEmail: ${Email}\nMessage: ${Message}\nSubmit Button: ${submitbutton}`,
    html: `<p>Name: ${Name}</p><p>Email: ${Email}</p><p>Message: ${Message}</p><p>Submit Button: ${submitbutton}</p>`,
  };

  sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Email sent successfully" });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.toString());
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to send email" });
    });
});

// Set up fallback for path module
resolve.fallback = { path: require.resolve("path-browserify") };

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

I'm wondering why I'm getting this POST request error and how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi,
it appears you exposed your API key in your question. I'd strongly recommend that you invalid this key ASAP to avoid that someone abuses it.

Comment: Regarding your question: 404 means your hitting the wrong endpoint. Is the backend running on a different port than the frontend? If so, try to proxy the backend service and only send the request to an absolute URL like "/send-email"

Comment: Hi, I tried this by modifying the axios POST request URL from "http://localhost:3000/send-email" to "/send-email" however I still get the same error: "POST http://localhost:3000/send-email 404 (Not Found)" ..

Comment: Everything looks ok. Are you sure your server has started correctly and is running up-to-date code? You should see the _`Server started on port 3000`_ message when it starts

Comment: Is the "Server started on port 3000" message supposed to be on my console? Because I don't see it there when I enter the site...

Comment: I see you edited the question. I would strongly recommend that you delete it as the API key can still be read in the version history of this question. And it seems you opened a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76667282/post-request-for-contact-form-is-not-working) anyway.

Comment: You're meant to see that _"Server started"_ message when you start your server. Typically this is done in a terminal via `npm start`, `node server.js`, or something like that

Comment: Well I get this message on my terminal "Compiled successfully!

You can now view **** in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://*****

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...
Issues checking in progress...
No issues found." so it's definitely working , just seems like the post request isn't when I check my console because there is an error